# Best algorithm to get same element index of a list of object in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-2.7

I have a list of object data which is has key and value. what is the best algorithm to get list of index element that has the same key.

This is the data:

```
parentElement = [
        {"key":"K","val":"sr"},
        {"key":"L","val":"sw"},
        {"key":"M","val":"se"},
        {"key":"M","val":"ss"},
        {"key":"M","val":"sq"},
        {"key":"K","val":"sf"},
        {"key":"L","val":"sv"},
        {"key":"M","val":"sf"},
        {"key":"K","val":"sv"},
    ]
```

and I want to get output something like:

```
{0: [5, 8], 1: [6], 2: [3, 4, 7]} or [[0,5,8],[1,6],[2,3,4,7]]
```

I have try to make the script and it's working, but maybe it's not good enough to handle a lot of data and take **a lot of time**:

```
childKey = "key"
parentElement = [
    {"key":"K","val":"sr"},
    {"key":"L","val":"sw"},
    {"key":"M","val":"se"},
    {"key":"M","val":"ss"},
    {"key":"M","val":"sq"},
    {"key":"K","val":"sf"},
    {"key":"L","val":"sv"},
    {"key":"M","val":"sf"},
    {"key":"K","val":"sv"},
]

identicalElementIndex = {}
for pid1, p1 in enumerate(parentElement):
    for pid2, p2 in enumerate(parentElement):
        if p1 and p2:
            if p1[childKey] == p2[childKey] and pid1 is not pid2:
                flag = True
                for ieIndex in identicalElementIndex.values():
                    if pid1 in ieIndex: flag = False
                if flag:
                    if not identicalElementIndex.has_key(pid1):
                        identicalElementIndex.update({pid1:[pid2]})
                    else:
                        identicalElementIndex[pid1].append(pid2)
        elif not p1: parentElement.pop(pid1)
        elif not p2: parentElement.pop(pid2)

print identicalElementIndex
```

**Can anyone suggest a better and faster way to do this?**
Thank you

Comment: You might want to ask at the Code Review site instead. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This question might be closed for being too broad because it's really 'what do you think? how can it be improved?'.  If your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for the SO format

Comment: Your algorithm is `O(n^2)` (which will perform terribly for big lists) because for every item in the list you're iterating over ever other item in the list, which isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(n^2) since it is two nested loops. Each single step of the outer loop you loop through the entire list in the inner loop. This means the time will increase dramatically as the list length increases.

It is also unnecessary. Instead, you can loop through once and just note which `key` value has been seen at each list index.

This works efficiently in a single pass:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od=OrderedDict()
for i, ld in enumerate(parentElement):
    od.setdefault(ld['key'], []).append(i)

>>> od
OrderedDict([('K', [0, 5, 8]), ('L', [1, 6]), ('M', [2, 3, 4, 7])])
>>> od.values() 
[[0, 5, 8], [1, 6], [2, 3, 4, 7]]
```

Since we are using an ordered dict, which maintains insertion order, no post sorting is required to create a list with the order of the original list. (Python 3.6 that is not necessary.)

Or, if you want the alternate representation:

```
>>> {l[0]:l[1:] for l in od.values()}   
{0: [5, 8], 1: [6], 2: [3, 4, 7]}
```

With this form, you do not need to use an Ordered Dict since the order does not matter for the mapping of the first element to the remainder elements.